# How to build vapor toolbox with vapor 3.x

Tags: swift, vapor

I would like to build vapor toolbox with the latest vapor 3.x.

However, Package.swift of vapor toolbox still has Vapor 2.x dependency.

```
.Package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/vapor.git", majorVersion: 2)
```

Does anyone knows why?

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to build it form source.

Your question is missing some information though. What are you trying to achieve ?

1. Do you want to create a new Vapor 3 project ?
2. Or do you want to add Vapor 3 to your existing project ?

---

### Creating a new Vapor 3.0.0 (GM) project:

If you want to create a new Vapor project, you need to use the `new` command. Since Vapor 3 hasn't been officially released yet (follow [vapor/#1647](https://github.com/vapor/vapor/pull/1647) and [documentation/#302](https://github.com/vapor/documentation/pull/302) for updates), you'll need to specify the beta branch:

```sh
vapor new --branch=beta
```

---

### Adding Vapor 3.0.0 (GM) to an existing project:

Add the following to your Package.swift file:

```swift
.package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/vapor.git", .branch("gm"))
```

Once it's released, you'll need to change it to:

```swift
.package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/vapor.git", from: "3.0.0"),
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I didn't know that Vapor 3 was not released yet. I'd like to install Vapor 3.x on a linux distribution that is not officially supported. I'll try after it is formally released.

Answer (score 1):

Update Vapor:

[Installing Vapor](https://mihaelamj.github.io/Installing%20Vapor/)

[Install new vapor app](https://mihaelamj.github.io/Make%20new%20Vapor%20App/)

Or just change the package version

```
.package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/vapor.git", from: "3.0.0-rc.2"),
```